# Return Multiple DataTable in C# 2005

Tags: c#, datatable

I have table1 and table2 in a class..

```
public DataTable sampletable (DataTable table1,DataTable table2)
{
     // How to return the two table(table1 and table2)
}
```

Advance thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public DataTable[] sampletable (DataTable table1,DataTable table2) 
{ 
    return new DataTable[] { table1, table2 };
}
```

Use an array.  And to retrieve a particular table:

```
DataTable[] dtArray = sampletable (YourFirstDt, YourSecondDt);

DataTable table1 = dtArray[0];
DataTable table2 = dtArray[1];
```

Comment: how to retrieve the value of table1 in a form?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they have the same schema, you can use the [`DataTable.Merge Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx)

```
public DataTable sampletable(DataTable table1, DataTable table2) 
{ 
    table1.Merge(table2);

    return table1;
}
```

> The Merge method is used to merge two DataTable objects that have
>   largely similar schemas. A merge is typically used on a client
>   application to incorporate the latest changes from a data source into
>   an existing DataTable. This allows the client application to have a
>   refreshed DataTable with the latest data from the data source.
>
> The merge operation takes into account only the original table, and the
>   table to be merged. Child tables are not affected or included. If a
>   table has one or more child tables, defined as part of a relationship,
>   each child table must be merged individually.
>
> When merging a new source DataTable into the target, any source rows
>   with a DataRowState value of Unchanged, Modified, or Deleted, is
>   matched to target rows with the same primary key values. Source rows
>   with a DataRowState value of Added are matched to new target rows with
>   the same primary key values as the new source rows.

Answer (score 1):

```html
public DataSet Getdatasettables()
{
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
 DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
 ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
 ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
 return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataSet , Create a new DataSet and Add the multiple tables to it ,
For Eg-

```
DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
DataTable Dt1= new DataTable();
Ds.Tables.Add(Dt1)
```

you can add multiple tables and to access the datatable you can use the index ( eg - 
 Ds.Tables[0])
Hope this answers your question!!.